# is there any solution for my datepicker validation in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, date, validation

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="data_1">
    <div class="input-group date" id="date1" data-date="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input type="text" onload="getDate()" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" value='<?php echo date(' m/d/Y '); ?>'>
    </div>
</div>
```

here i give my jquery

```
var mem = $('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    startDate: '-0m',

    autoclose: true
});
```

if i add the following code the validation is not working in my code

```
datepicker().$('#start_date').datepicker('setDate',new Date()) ;
```

Comment: Could you make sure you havn't done any typos in your code ? `datepicket().$(...)` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: please specify the proper issue which are you facing, use can for date picker validation :: $('#datepicker').valid() function on change of datepicker

Comment: what you want to validate

Comment: i validate my images that is present inside the same div section..